# SQLSTATE: 42000

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I've been trying to insert items into a SQL Server database using PHP but I keep getting back this error:

> SQLSTATE: 42000 code: 102 message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Here's the sql statement:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO [competitionTrade]
                       ([fullName]
                       ,[date]
                       ,[limitOrder]
                       ,[quantity]
                       ,[tickerSymbol]
                       ,[limitPrice]
                       ,[contingentOrder]
                       ,[contingentQuantity]
                       ,[contingentLimitPrice])
                 VALUES
                       (<$fullName, varchar(50),>
                       ,<$date, datetime,>
                       ,<$limitOrder, varchar(50),>
                       ,<$quantity, int,>
                       ,<$ticSymbol, varchar(50),>
                       ,<$limitPrice, float,>
                       ,<$contingentOrder, varchar(50),>
                       ,<$contingentQuantity, int,>
                       ,<$contingentLimitPrice, float,>)";
```

I'm not too sure where the syntax error is in this statement.

Comment: Why are you setting the field type in the INSERT, removed this and just insert the value

Comment: use PDO. search for best practices to building a safe query on PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is totally broken:

```
             VALUES
                   (<$fullName, varchar(50),>
                   ,<$date, datetime,>
```

That is **NOT** how you write an insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, ...., fieldN)
VALUES (value1, value2, ...., valueN)
```

You specify field types when you `CREATE` the table. And as written, if it were working, you are probably vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).l

Answer (score 1):

`<` is not valid syntax. It should just be `... VALUES ($fullName, $date, $limitOrder, $quantity, $ticSymbol, $limitPrice, $contingentOrder, $contingentQuantity, $contingentLimitPrice)";`

Insert statements does not require you to put field types, they just require the data you wish to insert.

I recommend reading up on how to bind variables to query to prevent SQL injection. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the field type on an INSERT statement.
Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO [competitionTrade]
                       ([fullName]
                       ,[date]
                       ,[limitOrder]
                       ,[quantity]
                       ,[tickerSymbol]
                       ,[limitPrice]
                       ,[contingentOrder]
                       ,[contingentQuantity]
                       ,[contingentLimitPrice])
                 VALUES
                       ($fullName,
                       $date,
                       $limitOrder,
                       $quantity,
                       $ticSymbol,
                       $limitPrice,
                       $contingentOrder,
                       $contingentQuantity,
                       $contingentLimitPrice";
```

Comment: asumming that the variables are safe, still not the best way to add variables. Use PDO